# bitrock installer - getting started for Linux

Tags: linux, qt, installation, uninstallation, bitrock

I have read the first few sections of "http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/docs/installbuilder-userguide/index.html" may be 3 to 4 times, but it is quite unclear to me.

I have a project/product that needs to be installed/unistalled/upgraded on user machines, so I guess I can make use of BitRock installer to accomplish the same. Having said that, below are my details:

Target system: Linux (can be 32 bit or 64 bit)
Project Developed using : Qt and C++ etc
For simplicity, if I call the name of the project directory as "Hello world" and my .pro file as "Hello world.pro" and my executable as "Hello world", how can I generate a package depending on the target system (debian or rpm based). As I said, I read the user guide but totally confused about how to integrate BitRock with my development system to generate installer, uninstaller or upgrade binaries.

All I did was download the bitrock installer for QT based Linux, changed the permission of the binary, executed it and chose the default options. Please help me with a simple example.

Btw, the most basic question is that, for me a double click on the installer "installbuilder-qt-8.6.0-linux-installer.run" does not work. No GUI comes up. I prefer to create my installer using the GUI, rather than manually writing XML files

Thanks

Comment: You really need to start it from the terminal and see what the error messages are, if any.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer to your question, but the what you are trying is not the standard way of deployment on Linux, instead of using .run file (hardly used) it is better to create debian and rpm packages which can be installed with a single click.

Since you are using Qt you can also try Qt installer framework, which helps you create cross-platform Window Style installers.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Installer-Framework

Comment: @Sandeep You will need to create rpm and deb packages yourself (quite easy) and if your application is opensource then they get automatically created if you upload your project src on launchpad etc.